# Currency type unable to compute sum formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

When using currency type, the formula =E2-F2 not working. But when cells formatted to number type, the same working. Currency type should also support sum formula!

[image]

On another sheet, the currency format works for sum formula:

[image]

I tried addressing formatting problem by selecting E and F columns and changing their type to currency. But still not able to compute sum. Could anyone please suggest a way to remove $ sign from all the cells in columns E and F and then try again. Manually removing the $ sign from each cell is the last option.

After applying ISTEXT, ISNUMBER functions, indeed E3 cell is showing true for text and false for number. This is despite the cell formatted as number.

[image]

[image]

After uploading to OneDrive and using online version of Excel, E3 cell is showing as number and computing sum.

Comment: Try using the `ISTEXT` and `ISNUMBER` functions to see the type of data held in your problem cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, Excel is extremely tolerant of cell entries that have actually been entered as text into a cell being treated as numbers if they look like a number. In computing terms, this is sometimes called *coercion*. Excel is very good at coercion.

So, for example, if `="1"` is entered into call `A1` and `="2"` is entered into cell `B1` then these two cells actually both contain text strings of length 1 character. Normally, text strings cannot be added together. If `A1` contained `a` and `B1` contained `b` then the formula `=A1+B1` would result in `#VALUE!` value error. However, when text strings are entered that look like numbers are entered into cells `A1` and `B1`, then Excel will use coercion to change the strings "1" and "2" to the numbers 1 and 2 and the formula `=A1+B1` will display the result 3 rather than a `#VALUE!` error.

Coercion, however, has its limits (as you have found). One such limit may depend on specific settings. For example, my own version of Excel (Office 365) readily coerces text strings beginning with the £ and € symbols to numbers but does not coerce text strings beginning with the $ symbol to numeric values. In fact, if I type `$1` as a cell entry, it is always treated and displayed as a 2 character text string and any arithmetic operations involving that cell result in a `#VALUE!` error.

There is clearly something in my set up of Excel (or possibly even my set up of Windows) that is causing this behaviour. Possibly something similar is causing the results you are  experiencing. You can check whether it any of the problem cells you report are being held as text by using the `ISTEXT()` function. If the cells are being held as text then it will be a coercion problem that is the source of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot, the cell format is not correct, as shown in the following picturem you can see the correct Currency format for cells:
[image]
In your picture the values is to the left in the cell, you should correct the cell format for incorrect values.

Comment: Updated the question. Kindly let me know a way to remove the $ sign from all the E and F cells content.

Comment: @Tecnosec, there is something very weird about the numbers showing in cells `E2`, `F2` and `L2` of your first two screenshots:  comma separators normally divide a number every three digits but yours are showing every two digits for the first eight digits. This probably explains why `=E2-F2` will cause a `#VALUE!` error but your second screenshot is not showing this error - rather, it is showing the error for `=E3-F3` and the values in these cells look OK. Even if they are text values rather than numbers, Excel is usually good at coercing text that looks like a number into a number.

Comment: After uploading to OneDrive and using online version of Excel, E3 cell is showing as number and computing sum.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you may well have bare numbers in cells, and DISPLAY them as CURRENCY;
Select (a) cell(s), then just hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, hit <kbd>1</kbd> and chose a display format; or create your own (custom format).

Look up number formatting in the help to see what you can do, the `TEXT()` function uses the same formatting. (Online; libreoffice help on "[number format codes](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.3/hr/text/shared/01/05020301.html?&DbPAR=SHARED&System=UNIX)", there might be slight differences)